# Invariant logarithm of a unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, invariant-subspace, unitary-matrices

We start with a finite dimensional unitary representation over $\mathbb C$ of some (compact) group $G$. In the matrix algebra, take a unitary matrix $U$ that is invariant under the conjugation action of $G$. Is it always possible to find a log of $U$ that is also invariant under the action of $G$? I know taking log of a unitary without regard to the action is easy since $U$ is diagonalizable. Thanks

How about infinite dimensions?

Comment: Now that I think about it, this is really the same as the problem without the the group action. Because being invariant means you can diagonalize $U$ together with the unitary matrices corresponding to the group actions simultaneously. Then taking log on each diagonal term automatically gives the invariant log desired.